# want to upload several pictures for a user, only allowing me to upload one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want users to be able to upload several pictures, but I can only get it to do one. here is my code:

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('profile/<int:user_id>', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/<int:user_id>/upload/', views.upload_pics, name='upload_pics'),


]
```

here is my view:

```
def upload_pics(request, user_id):

    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)

    if request.method == "POST":

        file_list = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        for afile in file_list:

            pic = File()
            pic.user = user_profile
            pic.image = afile
            pic.save()

            return redirect("groups:index")

    else:
        render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
    return render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
```

finally, here is the form(pic_upload.html):

```
<form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_pics' user.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select Pictures: </td><td><input name="files" type="file" size="50" accept="image/*" multiple>  </td>
        <td><button type="submit"> Upload </button> </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class File(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')
```

i've been trying to get this done for several days, but no luck. I've looked into formsets but simpler methods for accomplishing multiple file uploads seem to exist. any guidance as to why only 1 picture is being saved would really be appreciated. thanks ya'll

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your view and check `request.FILES`, does it contain multiple files?

Comment: The question title is very confusing and misleading. What's the difference between **several** and **more than one**?

Comment: your right, I changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def upload_pics(request, user_id):

    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)

    if request.method == "POST":

        file_list = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        for afile in file_list:

            pic = File()
            pic.user = user_profile
            pic.image = afile
            pic.save()

            return redirect("groups:index")

    else:
        render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
    return render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
```

to

```
def upload_pics(request, user_id):

    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)

    if request.method == "POST":

        file_list = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        for afile in file_list:

            pic = File()
            pic.user = user_profile
            pic.image = afile
            pic.save()

        return redirect("groups:index")

    else:
        render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
    return render(request, 'accounts/pic_upload.html')
```

`return redirect("groups:index")` shouldn't in `for` block,you should return after all for each run over,this is why only one file saved.

Comment: you are welcome,it will be better if you accept this as answer!